# Is there a way to auto-select specific tab when using navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I am currently working on a screen capturing feature in chrome using

`navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia`

I am only able to open a user selection where the user can choose from all the given displaymedias. Is there any way to go around the selection and select a tab via the tab name automaticly?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
I have read the privacy and security part in which it says that

> In addition, user permission is always required to access the user's audio and video inputs.

but im still wondering if there is a way?

Answer (score 14):

very few available constrains for getDisplayMedia

```
getDisplayMedia({preferCurrentTab:true}) // in chrome 96
```

hopefully getViewportMedia, getViewportScreenshot coming soon

Answer (score 0):

Try this command-line flag:

```
--auto-select-tab-capture-source-by-title="The target tab's title"
```